# How to use function with Animated.timing and setState?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-animated

I'm having trouble using an Animated.timing in conjunction with a setState.

```
export default function Main() {

  const [stateMenu, setStateMenu] = useState(false);
  const translateY = new Animated.Value(0);

  const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

function Descer() {
    Animated.timing(translateY, {
        toValue: 800,
        duration: 2000,
        useNativeDriver: false
    }).start();
}

//(1) - With the "Teste" function, this works perfectly.
function teste()
{
  Descer();
  //setStateMenu(!stateMenu);
}

//(2) - In this way nothing happens.
function teste()
{
  Descer();
  setStateMenu(!stateMenu);
}


  return (
    <Container>
      <Header onPress={() => teste()} state={stateMenu}/>
      <Scene>
        <Menu/>
        <ScenePage style={[{flex:1, position:'absolute', top:0, left:0, zIndex:15, width:'100%', height:height }, {top:translateY}]}>
          <Routes />
        </ScenePage>

      </Scene>

    </Container>
  )
};
```

I don't have two "Teste" functions, I put two just to explain what happens.

I need to use the second way, why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

To use `setStateMenu` with the previous state value you need to pass a function with the previous state as an argument. Try to change setStateMenu call like this:

```
setStateMenu(prevState => !prevState);
```

Comment: Sorry did not understand. What is "prevState"?

Comment: @Joelend When you use `setStateMenu` you cannot access `stateMenu` value directly, so the solution is to pass a function. And this function take the previous `stateMenu` value like argument, you can name this argument like you want (I name it prevState in this example). [See more in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Comment: I got it, I did it here ... just as it was before. Even with your suggestion, Animated.timing still doesn't run.